# "zsh: command not found:" when running Ruby commands

Tags: ruby, shell, path, zsh, macos-catalina

I still have core commands like ls or pwd working but certain commands relating to Ruby aren't recognised. Not sure if this would apply to other languages but I don't seem to be having any issues with npm or anything like that.

If it helps I'm also using
MacOS Catalina
Version 10.15.7

```
run `bundle update --bundler`
zsh: command not found: run
```

I don't know how to reset zsh or how to fix this. Here is the content of $PATH variable:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/peter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/peter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/Users/peter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/peter/.rvm/bin:/Users/peter/.rvm/bin:/Users/peter/.rvm/bin
```

When I run in my terminal 'vim ~/.zshrc' it returns the following

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/peter/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
# alias brewup=‘brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup; brew doctor’

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH
```

Any idea what the issue is or how to fix this? If you need me to provide any more information please let me know. I've never experienced this issue before so no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Tried that in VSCode and my Terminal same message of "undefined local variable or method `bundler' for main:Object (NameError)"

Comment: You should use `bundle update --bundler` directly without `run` in zsh. I guess you're mixing ruby code with zsh, but I don't know enough ruby to be sure.

Comment: I tried that earlier and that actually did the trick! Thank you! :) One thing I'm wondering about is if all future installs will be okay or if my $PATH variable is correct. So far everything seems to fine though.

Comment: @PeterStevens : You can fix PATH problems easily by yourself: Just print the `PATH` or `path` variable and see whether it contains the direcory where the program is located which you are going to execute (in your example: `run`). Of course this means that you have to know where you have installed your programs.

Answer (score 0):

### Fix *SHELL* and *PATH* Environment Variables

Either your PATH isn't being exported with the right SHELL variable, or you have some other PATH-related issues going on. You can fix this in a varierty of ways, but I'll suggest two of them.

Backticks run a command in your defined shell (e.g. `ENV['SHELL']`), so if zsh isn't your current *SHELL*, or if your shell isn't in your current PATH, then you're going to have issues. Either update your PATH before running your application, or add it in your Ruby script like so:

```
ENV['SHELL'] = '/bin/zsh'
ENV['PATH']  = [ENV['SHELL'], ENV['PATH']].join ?:
```

### Bypass Shell with Kernel#system

Alternatively, you can use the shell-free version of [Kernel#system](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) if you don't need to capture standard output. For example:

```
# this may not work if you're not using a system ruby
system('/path/to/bundle', 'update', '--bundler')
```

### More Global Fixes

Whatever approach you take, the problem is likely to be the same: you don't have an appropriate *SHELL* or *PATH* variable exported, so you may need to look at:

1. Your default user shell, e.g. `dscl . -read ~/ UserShell`.
2. Your shell's various startup files.
3. Your terminal settings, to ensure it's starting a login shell.

*Something* isn't set up right, either in your shell environment or your IDE, so you'll need to track it down. This should give you a head start.

Comment: Just an update, I noticed it seems to work fine if I just run 'bundle update --bundler' without the run bit in the beginning. Not sure how essential commands like run are though however.

Comment: "Backticks run a command in your defined shell" – Interesting, I didn't know that. I always thought they were hardwired depending on the OS to `cmd.exe` or `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : You are halfway correct. The defined shell **can** be overwritten by an environment variable, but this variable is not `SHELL`. It is `RUBYSHELL`, and if this is not set and we are on Windows, the variable `COMSPEC` is used. Only if the variables are not set, the standard (/bin/sh) is applied.